# HTTP_X_HEADER, X_HEADER or X-Header with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers

It looks like there are multiple ways of fetching headers using Rails. If the request has a header named `X-Header`, all of the three work:

1. `request.headers["HTTP_X_HEADER"]`
2. `request.headers["X_HEADER"]`
3. `request.headers["X-Header"]`

Which one should I use? Is there a convention over this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at implementation of Rails request header, you can see that the header name is "sanitized" first, passing it to the `Rack::Request::Env` object – https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/headers.rb#L122

```
    # Converts an HTTP header name to an environment variable name if it is
    # not contained within the headers hash.
    def env_name(key)
      key = key.to_s
      if HTTP_HEADER.match?(key)
        key = key.upcase.tr("-", "_")
        key = "HTTP_" + key unless CGI_VARIABLES.include?(key)
      end
      key
    end
```

Rails will `upcase` the header name for you, as well as convert `-` to `_` and prepend the `HTTP_` if needed.

Taking this in consideration:

`request.headers["HTTP_X_APPENGINE_COUNTRY"]` – I'd avoid this one, as Rails will prepend `HTTP_`.

`request.headers["X_APPENGINE_COUNTRY"]` – I see nothing wrong with useing this one.

`request.headers["X-AppEngine-Country"]` – This is the one I'd choose, since the header name is in its original format.

Cheers!